# How to limit number of threads/sub-processes used in a function in bash

Tags: bash

My question  is how change this code so it will use only 4 threads/sub-processes?

```
TESTS="a b c d e"

for f in $TESTS; do
  t=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
  sleep $t && echo $f $t &
done
wait
```

Comment: These are not threads, but sub-processes.

Comment: Could you please consider accepting an answer and changing "threads" to "sub-processes" in your question? Using the wrong words makes it harder to find on the web! ;-)

Answer (score 43):

Interesting question. I tried to use xargs for this and I found a way.

Try this:

```
seq 10 | xargs -i --max-procs=4 bash -c "echo start {}; sleep 3; echo done {}"
```

`--max-procs=4` will ensure that no more than four subprocesses are running at a time.

The output will look like this:

```
start 2
start 3
start 1
start 4
done 2
done 3
done 1
done 4
start 6
start 5
start 7
start 8
done 6
done 5
start 9
done 8
done 7
start 10
done 9
done 10
```

Note that the order of execution might not follow the commands in the order you submit them. As you can see 2 started before 1.

Comment: BusyBox `xargs` does not have a `--max-procs` option though.

Comment: @Livy It seems like `-P` would do it. Try this: `docker run --rm busybox sh -c "seq 10 | xargs -I'{}' -P 4 sh -c 'echo start {}; sleep 3; echo done {}'"`

Comment: `--max-procs` and `-P` options are the same. On OpenWrt 19.07, neither option is available. I don't know if it is unavailable on BusyBox, or they removed it during compilation to save space. I had to write my custom script to handle this, which is quite lengthy, and probably slow compared to native C code.

Answer (score 21):

Quick and dirty solution: insert this line somewhere inside your `for` loop:

```
while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge 4 ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

(assumes you don't already have other background jobs running in the same shell)

Comment: this might be a very wee bit more efficient with `jobs -r` - without it, you'll count the lines where bash tells you which jobs are already done.

Comment: This solution is great. I just insert the line at the right place and boom! 
I liked that I didn't need to change my script structure at all

Answer (score 12):

I have found another solution for this question using `parallel` (part of `moreutils` package.)

```
parallel -j 4 -i bash -c "echo start {}; sleep 2; echo done {};" -- $(seq 10)
```

`-j 4` stands for `-j maxjobs`

`-i`   uses the parameters as {}

`--`   delimits your arguments

The output of this command will be:

```
start 3
start 4
start 1
start 2
done 4
done 2
done 3
done 1
start 5
start 6
start 7
start 8
done 5
done 6
start 9
done 7
start 10
done 8
done 9
done 10
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this by using the `jobs` builtin:

```
for f in $TESTS; do
  running=($(jobs -rp))
  while [ ${#running[@]} -ge 4 ] ; do
    sleep 1   # this is not optimal, but you can't use wait here
    running=($(jobs -rp))
  done
  t=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
  sleep $t && echo $f $t &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 7):

GNU Parallel is designed for this kind of tasks:

```
TESTS="a b c d e"
for f in $TESTS; do
  t=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
  sem -j4 sleep $t && echo $f $t
done
sem --wait
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

This tested script runs 5 jobs at a time and will restart a new job as soon as it does (due to the kill of the sleep 10.9 when we get a SIGCHLD. A simpler version of this could use direct polling (change the sleep 10.9 to sleep 1 and get rid of the trap).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -o monitor
trap "pkill -P $$ -f 'sleep 10\.9' >&/dev/null" SIGCHLD

totaljobs=15
numjobs=5
worktime=10
curjobs=0
declare -A pidlist

dojob()
{
  slot=$1
  time=$(echo "$RANDOM * 10 / 32768" | bc -l)
  echo Starting job $slot with args $time
  sleep $time &
  pidlist[$slot]=`jobs -p %%`
  curjobs=$(($curjobs + 1))
  totaljobs=$(($totaljobs - 1))
}

# start
while [ $curjobs -lt $numjobs -a $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  dojob $curjobs
 done

# Poll for jobs to die, restarting while we have them
while [ $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  for ((i=0;$i < $curjobs;i++))
   do
    if ! kill -0 ${pidlist[$i]} >&/dev/null
     then
      dojob $i
      break
     fi
   done
   sleep 10.9 >&/dev/null
 done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my "parallel" unzip loop using bash on AIX:

```
for z in *.zip ; do
  7za x $z >/dev/null
  while [ $(jobs -p|wc -l) -ge 4 ] ; do
    wait -n
  done
done
```

Notes:

- *jobs -p*     (bash function) lists jobs of immediate parent
- *wait -n*     (bash function) waits for any (one) background process to
  finish