# Running a limited number of child processes in parallel in bash?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a large set of files for which some heavy processing needs to be done.
This processing in single threaded, uses a few hundred MiB of RAM (on the machine used to start the job) and takes a few minutes to run.
My current usecase is to start a hadoop job on the input data, but I've had this same problem in other cases before.

In order to fully utilize the available CPU power I want to be able to run several those tasks in paralell.

However a very simple example shell script like this will trash the system performance due to excessive load and swapping:

```
find . -type f | while read name ; 
do 
   some_heavy_processing_command ${name} &
done
```

So what I want is essentially similar to what "gmake -j4" does.

I know bash supports the "wait" command but that only waits untill all child processes have completed. In the past I've created scripting that does a 'ps' command and then grep the child processes out by name (yes, i know ... ugly).

What is the simplest/cleanest/best solution to do what I want?

---

Edit: Thanks to Frederik: Yes indeed this is a duplicate of [How to limit number of threads/sub-processes used in a function in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash)
The "xargs --max-procs=4" works like a charm.
(So I voted to close my own question)

Comment: it seems like a job for [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), but I'm not sure it adds extra power to `xargs --max-procs`, which I didn't know

Comment: @Niels: I've been using `screen` for the purpose, though it's a bit messy this way, especially when started from within another `screen` session ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -o monitor 
# means: run background processes in a separate processes...
trap add_next_job CHLD 
# execute add_next_job when we receive a child complete signal

todo_array=($(find . -type f)) # places output into an array

index=0
max_jobs=2

function add_next_job {
    # if still jobs to do then add one
    if [[ $index -lt ${#todo_array[*]} ]]
    # apparently stackoverflow doesn't like bash syntax
    # the hash in the if is not a comment - rather it's bash awkward way of getting its length
    then
        echo adding job ${todo_array[$index]}
        do_job ${todo_array[$index]} & 
        # replace the line above with the command you want
        index=$(($index+1))
    fi
}

function do_job {
    echo "starting job $1"
    sleep 2
}

# add initial set of jobs
while [[ $index -lt $max_jobs ]]
do
    add_next_job
done

# wait for all jobs to complete
wait
echo "done"
```

Having said that Fredrik makes the excellent point that xargs does exactly what you want...

Comment: I now understand the code, but had to think a bit. Especially the part about why these would run in parallel (well, because they are subprocesses) eluded me. I think it would be worthwhile adding comments for that part into the code as well.

Comment: Although my current application works great with the xargs --max-procs I'm still giving you the credit for being "the answer" because your script is usable in more situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

I know I'm late to the party with this answer but I thought I would post an alternative that, IMHO, makes the body of the script cleaner and simpler. (Clearly you can change the values 2 & 5 to be appropriate for your scenario.)

```
function max2 {
   while [ `jobs | wc -l` -ge 2 ]
   do
      sleep 5
   done
}

find . -type f | while read name ; 
do 
   max2; some_heavy_processing_command ${name} &
done
wait
```

Comment: This worked for me after changing the while syntax to: while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge 2 ]

Comment: Note that the command is very long, it may take several lines to show it. In that case, `jobs -p` should do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

With GNU Parallel it becomes simpler:

```
find . -type f | parallel  some_heavy_processing_command {}
```

Learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a more handy solution using [make](/questions/tagged/make):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

THIS := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
TARGETS := $(shell find . -name '*.sh' -type f)

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS)

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS):
        some_heavy_processing_command $@

$(THIS): ; # Avoid to try to remake this makefile
```

Call it as e.g. 'test.mak', and add execute rights. If You call `./test.mak` it will call the `some_heavy_processing_command` one-by-one. But You can call as `./test.mak -j 4`, then it will run four subprocesses at once. Also You can use it on a more sophisticated way: run as `./test.mak -j 5 -l 1.5`, then it will run maximum 5 sub-processes while the system load is under 1.5, but it will limit the number of processes if the system load exceeds 1.5.

It is more flexible than [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs), and [make](/questions/tagged/make) is part of the standard distribution, not like `parallel`.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked quite well for me.

I noticed one issue in which the script couldn't end.
If you run into a case where the script wont end due to  max_jobs being greater than the number of elements in the array, the script will never quit.

To prevent the above scenario, I've added the following right after the "max_jobs" declaration.

```
if [ $max_jobs -gt ${#todo_array[*]} ];
    then
           # there are more elements found in the array than max jobs, setting max jobs to #of array elements"
            max_jobs=${#todo_array[*]}
 fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
PARALLEL_MAX=...
function start_job() {
  while [ $(ps --no-headers -o pid --ppid=$$ | wc -l) -gt $PARALLEL_MAX ]; do
    sleep .1  # Wait for background tasks to complete.                         
  done
  "$@" &
}
start_job some_big_command1
start_job some_big_command2
start_job some_big_command3
start_job some_big_command4
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a very good function I used to control the maximum # of jobs from bash or ksh. NOTE: the - 1 in the pgrep subtracts the wc -l subprocess.

```
function jobmax
{
    typeset -i MAXJOBS=$1
    sleep .1
    while (( ($(pgrep -P $$ | wc -l) - 1) >= $MAXJOBS ))
    do
        sleep .1
    done
}

nproc=5
for i in {1..100}
do
    sleep 1 &
    jobmax $nproc
done
wait # Wait for the rest
```