# How to run parallel for loops

Tags: bash

I'm not very familiar with bash, but I would like split up this code such that I can run it on a server with 12 processors:

```
#!/bin/bash
#bashScript.sh
for i in {1..209}
do

Rscript Compute.R $i

done
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on linux? In particular, do you have the [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) utility?

Comment: That answer might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593531/running-a-limited-number-of-child-processes-in-parallel-in-bash

Answer (score 4):

Use `xargs` with the option `--max-procs` (`-P`). If there are enough arguments, `xargs` will use exactly this number of concurrent processes to process the input:

```
#! /bin/bash
seq 209 |
xargs -P12 -r -n1 Rscript Compute.R
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
#bashScript.sh
for i in {1..209}
do

Rscript Compute.R $i &

done
```

Comment: That's going to run all 209 instances at once, with likely worse performance than desired... Not to mention, possibly running out of memory...

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel Rscript Compute.R ::: {1..209}
```

10 seconds installation:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1