# running -- an initially unknown -- number of bash commands in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, tail, gnu-parallel

I would like to be able to run a series of commands without knowing in advance how many and which exactly. These commands are usually some calculations each taking some hours/days. I need some way to modify the list of commands *a posteriori* because it runs on a cluster and I need to reserve the nodes in advance.

I would like it (whatever *it* is) to (i) read commands while it is running and keep launching them as processors free up, and (ii) exit when no more commands are running.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

**EDIT : this works (with GNU parallel)**

First, as suggested in answers, modify `parallel` (e.g. `/usr/bin/parallel`), changing

```
# Ignore the rest of input file
while (<$fh>) {}
```

to

```
# Ignore the rest of input file
close $fh;
```

then test like this:

```
seq 10 > test;   tail -f test | parallel -uE EXIT 'echo {}'
```

NOTES

- "-u" is for "ungroup" so that all lines are read, executed and printed as they come and procs are available
- "-E EXIT" is so we can kill : after writing EXIT another (arbitrary) string must be written so that 'tail -f' will die. (without the modification above parallel will keep the stream open and this will not work)
- it will not quit if the stream is empty AND cpus are idle: i think this is a more complicated problem, also involving synchronization, although it could be done by something like `if(items_processed>0 && nprocs_running==0) exit`. Then there is still the issue of killing tail but this could hacked around in an ugly way by writing some bogus to the input file periodically.

---

**what I've tried**

The simplest syntax I can think of would be something like this, using GNU parallel :

```
parallel < command-list.txt
[...some time later...]
echo "this-command-I-forgot" >> command-list.txt
```

This works great... except, if the number of commands is smaller than the number of CPUs (which is common, I might start with 10 processes on a 16-cpu machine) it will encounter an EOF, close the stream and I see no way of adding further commands. So it will finish whenever those running commands have ended.

To avoid the EOF problem I thought I could follow the stream with tail

```
tail -n+0 -f command-list.txt | parallel --eof=EXIT
```

For example as in this simple test:

```
seq 10 > command-list.txt
tail -n+0 -f command-list.txt | parallel -j2 --eof=EXIT 'sleep 1 && echo {}'
echo "this-command-I-forgot" >> command-list.txt
```

**This gets very close**, I can add commands and it doesn't close the file.
However, it never gets to the end and doesn't stop when reading 'EXIT' but hangs instead. I am not sure why. Perhaps it is reading in blocks.(??)
Also, it would not stop if all processes are finished **and** there is nothing left to do in the file.

(*edit* this possibly related to a bug as proposed in the answers)

Alternatively I can imagine something, launching some child processes for each CPU with 'wait PID' but it appears overcomplicated, and moreover this seems exactly the kind of thing GNU/parallel should made to do.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

---

**edit**
based on comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found), this at least exits, but it requires the keyword 'EXIT' to be there in the first place.

```
sh -c 'tail -n+0 -f command-list.txt | { sed "/EXIT/Q" && kill -9 $$ ;}' | parallel -j2  'sleep 1 && echo {}'
```

---

as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593531/running-a-limited-number-of-child-processes-in-parallel-in-bash), one can also use 'xargs -P2' instead of 'parallel -j2', though that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That's nice but is it really necessary to kill? I think just quitting would be enough. Or may be add `; exit` to your shell command.

Comment: @konsolebox sorry, in fact it didn't do what I what. I removed it while you were commenting. It requires the 'EXIT' keyword to be present in the file in the first place.  I think it is necessary to kill it though, since tail would keep it open forever otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill for your problem, but you could use [Bosco](http://bosco.opensciencegrid.org/) for that.

What it does is request some resources from the cluster (many job schedulers are supported) and then you have a local queue system running on your laptop so you can submit jobs locally and they will be 'glied in' the allocation on the cluster.

You can submit as many tasks as you want to your local Bosco install and it will take care of actually running them on the cluster taking into account the number of CPU that were allocated.

If you forget one task, you simply submit one more to your local Bosco install and it will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks but it indeed seems a bit overkill for my purpose. I would prefer a small script solution but I might look into it if when I need something more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 4< <(exec tail -n+0 -f command-list.txt)
TAIL_PID=$!
exec 5> >(exec parallel -j2 'sleep 1 && echo {}')

while IFS= read -ru 4 __; do
    if [[ $__ == EXIT ]]; then
        exec 4<&- 5>&-
        kill -s SIGHUP "$TAIL_PID"
        break
    fi
    echo "$__" >&5
done
```

Comment: very nice, this indeed allows insertion of new commands and stops upon finding 'EXIT'. The only part is that it doesn't stop when commands and jobs run out. Perhaps it could be added to the 'if' somehow? I never used 'exec' but if I understand correctly the first exec lines open file descriptors, and 'exec 4<&- 5>&-' closes them. However would you mind explaining what the dollar double underscore does?

Comment: @jaap I probably wasn't able to read your edit. `__` is just a normal variable.

Comment: @jaap That may be difficult as the command reads whole input at once even before new input is sent. Well you can ask another question about it, but with respect to your original requirement, that's the answer I can give.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be hit by a possible bug in GNU `parallel` and a possible bug in `tail`.

In GNU Parallel change the following from:

```
        # Ignore the rest of input file                                                                   
        while (<$fh>) {}
```

to:

```
        # Ignore the rest of input file                                                                   
        close $fh;
```

Then use:

```
tail -n+0 -f command-list.txt | (parallel -j2 --eof=EXIT {}; echo Parallel is now done; (seq 1000 >> command-list.txt &);echo Done appending dummy data)
```

Finish up with:

```
echo pwd >> command-list.txt
echo "EXIT" >> command-list.txt
```

As you can see `parallel` finishes up nicely - it is `tail` that is hanging, but the final `seq` which is made after `parallel` finishes, makes `tail` understand that we are done.

`tail` has the same behaviour on FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Debian GNU/Linux, so while the behaviour is sub-optimal, it is probably not going to be considered a bug.

Comment: I wrote to the parallel mailing list after your comment. The issue of 'not reading to the end' can be overcome by using the '-u' flag (for ungroup). I modified the original questions with a solution that will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. I realize now that you are the maintainer who answered in the mailing list! :) Thanks I think the '-u' was what I needed.

Comment: Also, I guess you're right that `tail` not dying is probably bug : for example, this exits tail `touch test; tail -f test | true` but this does not `touch test; tail -f test | sleep 1`.

Comment: Be warned when you use -u: Read the manual, so you know what problems that may cause.