# How to execute a bunch of commands from a file with concurrency control?

Tags: linux, xargs

I have a file with following items:

```
echo 1 ; sleep 2
echo 2 ; sleep 2
echo 3 ; sleep 2
echo 4 ; sleep 2
echo 5 ; sleep 2
echo 6 ; sleep 2
echo 7 ; sleep 2
```

What is the best way of iterating through it executing each line with concurrency control (max 2 items at a time). I was thinking about using xargs but no luck so far with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a limited number of child processes in parallel in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593531/running-a-limited-number-of-child-processes-in-parallel-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file.txt
echo 1 ; sleep 1
echo 2 ; sleep 1
echo 3 ; sleep 1
echo 4 ; sleep 1
...
echo 13 ; sleep 1
echo 14 ; sleep 1
```

Running it with xargs parallelization:

```
xargs -a file.txt -I CMD --max-procs=2 sh -c CMD
```

This seems to produce some output, but is mostly sequential although once in a while, you get independent output:

```
1
3
2
4
...
13
14
```

- `-I` option replaces each command read with a replacement, in this case `CMD`
- `sh -c CMD` basically says what to with each command.
- `-c` tells sh that the command will come from a command string

Perhaps running it with commands that require a bit more processing will show a hint of parallelization

Comment: GNU `parallel` would be an alternative to `xargs` and provides a lot more flexibility, despite not being quite as ubiquitous...