# waiting on jobs in bash, allowing for a limited parallel jobs at one time, and then for all to finish to continue with the rest of the pipeline

Tags: bash

I am running GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). 
I have a specific question pertaining to waiting on jobs run in sub-shells, based on the max number of parallel processes I want to allow, and then wait for the remaining sub-shell jobs to finish before the next step is executed in the pipeline (if I am making proper sense here)..

Essentially,my pseudo code looks like this:

```
    MAX_PROCS=3
    for (( k = 0 ; $k < $kmerlen ; k += 1 ))
    do
    (
     ### Running a perl script here for each k (this script is a memory hog)...
    )&
    while [ $(ps -e | grep 'perlScriptAbove' | grep -v grep | wc -l) -gt ${MAX_PROCS} ] ; 
    do
       wait
    done

    done

    ###wait <- works fine without this wait, but I need all kmerlen jobs to finish first to proceed to the next part of the pipeline
    ## Run the rest of the pipeline...
```

The first wait statement in the while loop works fine spawning 3 jobs, but when I use the next wait statement, that property is lost, and the number of sub-shells spawned are equal to my kmerlen

My apologies if this has been answered before, but I didn't seem to find one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: look at this post. It could help: [how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash/).

Comment: The xargs with the max-procs argument is new to me - very sharp! This is going into my toolbox from now on - Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply calling `wait` should wait for **all** the background jobs executed by the shell, it looks like that's exactly what u need.

I.e. your code should be something like:

```
while (not all jobs spawned) # i.e. you want to do 40 jobs
  spawn as much jobs as you need in parallel (i.e. 4 jobs)
  wait
```

Comment: However, I intend to spawn only a limited number of background jobs (these are memory intensive), at a time...

Comment: Thank You. I'm still not so sure why my method didn't work, but took your advice and did this instead, after the for loop:                 if [[ `expr ${k} % ${MAX}` -eq 0 ]] && [[ ${k} -ne 0 ]];then                                                              wait ### Wait for all 3 jobs that have been spawned                                                              fi                                                                  Using a different pair of eyes helped. Thanks very much!

Comment: @SirishaS - and now you can select the answer as the chosen one and vote it up :)

Answer (score 3):

GNU Parallel is made for this kind of tasks. Gzip all txt-files in parallel and cat them together into a big .gz file:

```
parallel gzip -c ::: *.txt > out.gz
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly bash, but does do what you're asking:
[parallel-jobs](http://asymmetrical-view.com/personal/code/perl/parallel-jobs) is a perl program I made to do exactly this. You specify a file of "jobs", where each line is a job (a bash one liner), and a maximum number of jobs to execute in parallel and it will keep that many running until all the jobs have been completed.

It works with the standard install of perl (no additional modules required).  You may also want to look into gnu parallel, which is very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the code Kyle. Your way might be more robust in capturing the exit status of all child processes spawned as a subset...? With your permission I'd like to play around and use your code. Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely, it is in the public domain so feel free :)