# running a limited number of parallel programs using a script

Tags: linux, bash

Based on [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash) I am trying to develop a script that would limit the number of processes running to 4. However as an alternative I want the jobs to be stored in an array that I reference by index. I have written the following:

```
todo_array[1]="echo start1;sleep 3;echo done1"
todo_array[2]="echo start2;sleep 3;echo done2"
todo_array[3]="echo start3;sleep 3;echo done3"
todo_array[4]="echo start4;sleep 3;echo done4"
todo_array[5]="echo start5;sleep 3;echo done5"
todo_array[6]="echo start6;sleep 3;echo done6"
todo_array[7]="echo start7;sleep 3;echo done7"
todo_array[8]="echo start8;sleep 3;echo done8"
todo_array[9]="echo start9;sleep 3;echo done9"

max_jobs=4

seq ${#todo_array[@]} | xargs -i --max-procs=$max_jobs bash -c $todo_array[{}]
```

however when I execute I am getting an empty 9 newlinex output.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**EDIT**: I modified it to

```
seq ${#todo_array[@]} | xargs -i --max-procs=$max_jobs bash -c "$todo_array[{}]"
```

and I am getting the following weird output:

```
start1
start1
start1
start1
done1[2]
done1[3]
done1[1]
done1[4]
start1
start1
start1
start1
done1[5]
done1[6]
done1[7]
done1[8]
start1
done1[9]
```

Comment: I don't get empty newlines if I run your script. I get these 4 lines of errors: `bash: [3]: command not found
bash: [2]: command not found
bash: [4]: command not found
bash: [1]: command not found`

Comment: I think you probably want "&" (to run the jobs in parallel), and "$$" (to track the PID of each background job you've started).

Comment: Array referencing requires curly braces, e.g. `${todo_array[1]}`. However, `xargs -IX --max-procs=$max_jobs bash -c "${todo_array[X]}"` doesn't work for me, not sure why.

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer below. There's probably a more elegant way to write it, but it works for me on Ubuntu 11.10 (bash 4.2.10). May have been something to do with xargs not being able to dereference the array elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

todo_array[1]="echo start1;sleep 3;echo done1"
todo_array[2]="echo start2;sleep 3;echo done2"
todo_array[3]="echo start3;sleep 3;echo done3"
todo_array[4]="echo start4;sleep 3;echo done4"
todo_array[5]="echo start5;sleep 3;echo done5"
todo_array[6]="echo start6;sleep 3;echo done6"
todo_array[7]="echo start7;sleep 3;echo done7"
todo_array[8]="echo start8;sleep 3;echo done8"
todo_array[9]="echo start9;sleep 3;echo done9"

max_jobs=4

for i in "${todo_array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done | xargs -IX --max-procs=$max_jobs bash -c "X"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your question is not educational but simply "how to run a limited number of parallel programs", my advice would be not use a script and reinvent the wheel but use [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) instead, which is exactly made for that purpose.

Just create a scripts with your commands, and pipe it in to parallel, i.e.

```
./myScript.sh | parallel -j2
```

In the example, parallel will run two jobs in parallel, but will gather the output of the scripts at the end, just like if you had actually executed the scripts one after the other. Of course, the tasks ought to be independent; the question is not clear on that intent.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in checking out [ppss](http://code.google.com/p/ppss/). It's a easy to use powerful threader for scripting/shell stuff.