# Multiple Wait Commands

Tags: bash, for-loop, wait, background-process, child-process

I haven't been able to thoroughly concise my question, which means search engines can't give me a straight answer, and I've used this site in the past many times, so it's time I ask my own question..

So, I have a script (in bash) that runs through my list of pictures and determines if they need to be resized, which works well. I want to have a maximum of 3 running at a time. This is what I have.

```
if [ "$COUNT" = "$(echo "$(cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep processor|wc -l)+1"|bc)" ] ;then
    wait
    COUNT="0"
fi
```

Above, I set a COUNT variable to 0, and append 1 in a for loop (the same for loop that runs the convert statement). Once it hits (in this case) 3, (number of processors+1), it will 'wait' until the childs are done, then continue.

This is all fine and dandy, but let's say all my images are 48k, except for 1 which is 250mb (not true, but for explanation purposes). Somewhere down the line, the script would wait for that ONE picture when the rest could be running.

So finally, my question. Given the context and background info above, is there a way (using the 'wait' command or not) to have a script stop at 3 (processors+1) childs, and only execute 1 as one finishes? In context, is there a way to have 2 pictures running while the 250mb picture is doing its thing, then have 3 once it finishes? As opposed to what I do now, just wait for all 3, then execute 3 more.

Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Comment: check this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) xargs didn't work in the scenario, but the jobs function did! Thank you :)