# Run independent simulation on different cores (parallelize)

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run the same simulation with different parameters a lot of times on a cluster. Doing that I want to run one simulation on one core. I have 24 cores available, and need to run about 70 simulations. 
The parameters are specified by the path, top layer folder and second layer and in each leaf there is a specific run script which takes these parameters and run the simulation.

The script I need help with, should therefore just find all leaves and then run each script located there. This should be done such that I at (almost) all time have 23 leaf scripts running on each available core.

I have already made my own, which can be seen here:

```
#jump to working directory
if [ -z "$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Running from cmd in $PWD"
else 
    cd "$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR"
    echo "Nodes: $SLURM_NODELIST"
    echo "Running from queue in $PWD"
fi

find * -mindepth 2  -name run.sh | xargs -n 1 -P 24 bash
```

however piping to xargs, correctly start the first 23 simulations, but once they finish, it does not start a new one. How can I correct this?

Comment: Are you familiar with [gnu `parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: Nevermind, it might not even be available at your cluster...

Comment: I can install smaller programs in my home folder. It seems like what I need, so i'll definitely look into it and report back, whether it works.

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14387296/3577054) and maybe the whole thread. Or even [this thread too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/).

Comment: Have you tried `-L 1` instead of `-n 1`?